# nt!KiFastCallEntry or nt!ZwYieldExecution+0xa30

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, x86, windbg

"*rdmsr 176*" in Windbg in Kernel Debugging mode on local machine gives

*msr[176] = 00000000`82c3f8d0*

However disassembling the function at 82c3fsd0 gives nt!ZwYieldExecution+0aa30 rather than nt!KiFastCallEntry

[image: WinDbg Capture]

Is there something wrong?

Comment: What's the address for `KiFastCallEntry`? Note that the large-ish offset from `ZwYieldExecution` means it's probably not that function, it's just the nearest label the disassembler could find.

Comment: are your symbols right  ? lkd> .foreach /pS 2 (place {rdmsr 176}) { u place l2}
nt!KiFastCallEntry:
8053d560 b923000000      mov     ecx,23h
8053d565 6a30            push    30h
lkd>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the assembly instructions are right, they match the results from my test system:

```
kd> rdmsr 176
msr[176] = 00000000`81928230
kd> u 81928230
nt!KiFastCallEntry:
81928230 b923000000      mov     ecx,23h
81928235 6a30            push    30h
81928237 0fa1            pop     fs
81928239 8ed9            mov     ds,cx
8192823b 8ec1            mov     es,cx
8192823d 648b0d40000000  mov     ecx,dword ptr fs:[40h]
81928244 8b6104          mov     esp,dword ptr [ecx+4]
81928247 6a23            push    23h
```

Try reloading your symbols and see if that helps:

```
kd> .symfix
kd> .reload
```